# iptables in old xen kernel

Tags: iptables

Anyone have ever resolved/or have a work-around for an iptables problem with old xen kernel like below? Can't upgrade the xen kernel because it is a AWS EC2 kernel.
Thanks!

```
# uname -rmi
2.6.16-xenU i686 i386
# which iptables
/sbin/iptables
# iptables --list
iptables v1.3.5: can't initialize iptables table `filter': iptables who? (do you need to insmod?) Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

Comment: dumb question i know, but do you need to use iptables ? EC-2 has security groups, and it'll prevent you locking yourself out of the machine if you use those.

Answer (score 1):

Basically your kernel is not old, iptables-related modules are just not loaded. Have you tried `modprobe ip_tables`? What distro are you on? I use Ubuntu 12.04 on an EC2 instance and I do not have such problem.